# Can't request from website multiple times

Tags: javascript, json, request, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a pokedex for a school project, and am using JS for doing so. I found this api called pokeapi, and since it uses JSON, I thought of just getting the data in the page and returning a json of it, however when I try to use the method I created to do a request in a for loop, it doesn't seem to work, only working on the last element of the for loop:

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

const getJSON = (link, action) => {
  request.open("GET", link);
  request.send();
  request.onload = () => {
    if (request.status === 200) {
      let json = JSON.parse(request.response);
      action(json);
    } else {
      console.log(`e:${request.status} ${request.statusText}`);
    }
  }
}


let counter = 1;

getJSON("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/1/", (json) => {
  json.pokemon_entries.forEach((poke_entry) => {
    getJSON(poke_entry.pokemon_species.url, (poke_sp) => {
      console.log(poke_sp);
      //console loggin poke_sp only shows one console log, the last member of `json.pokemon_entries`
    })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have created a single XHR object.

Every time you make a request with it,  you cancel the previous request.

Create a new XHR object (inside the getJSON function) for each request.

i.e. swap the order of

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

and

```
const getJSON = (link, action) => {
```

Comment: It's flakey in some browsers doing multiple requests, and it can't do multiple requests at the *same time*.